# Zip Files using dontnetzip

Tags: c#, zip

I want to replace some files by adding them to a zip file. I mean after the zip is created, I should no longer see those files in the folder.

I'm able to zip files using dotNetZip's Library. But the orignal files are still there. Since I've already zipped them I no longer want them in that folder.

I tried deleting them(using file.delete) but I got an error that the files were being used by a program.

Here's what I wrote: //edited

```
var files = directory.GetFiles("*.csv", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
            try
            {

                using (Ionic.Zip.ZipFile zip = new Ionic.Zip.ZipFile())
                {

                    foreach (var file in files)
                    {


                        sendEmail.SendMailMessage(file.FullName);


           //           zip.AddFile(file.FullName);



                    }


    //    zip.Save(Path.Combine(filePath,dirDate, "logs.zip"));


                }

                foreach (var file in files)
                {
                    File.Delete(file.FullName);
                }

            }


            catch (Exception e)
            {

                Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            }





        }
```

This might be silly but I'm really stuck. Please guide.

The error I get is :

```
System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file 'D:\***.csv' because it is being used by another process.
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.File.InternalDelete(String path, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.File.Delete(String path)
   at Program.Main(String[] args) in d:\Documents\\**
```

Comment: You are missing a `}`, do you have the folder opened in `Explorer`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you're not using any `File.Delete()` method - please always provide the code that creates the error.

However, most likely you're simply trying to delete the files within your `using`-block. When you add the files to your zip file they will be accessed and locked, so you can't delete him. Once the `ZipFile` object is released the files will be released too.

```
var files = directory.GetFiles("*.csv", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

using (Ionic.Zip.ZipFile zip = new Ionic.Zip.ZipFile())
{
    foreach (var file in files)
    {
        zip.AddFile(file.FullName);
    }

    zip.Save(Path.Combine(filePath, dirDate, "logs.zip"));
}

// Outside of using block
foreach (var file in files)
{
    File.Delete(file.FullName);
}
```

Comment: I would rather store the filenames in a list first, because hypothetically a new csv file could be created during the zip process and you would delete it while it is not added to the zip file.

Comment: @Silvermind Good point, I changed my code accordingly. I also added `Path.Combine` instead of the manual concatenation of path.

Comment: I did what you suggested[made the edit in the code]. But I'm getting the same error.

Comment: Please see, I've copied the entire code block. It seems to throw the error if I call SendMailMessage method. If I comment it out, delete works fine.

Comment: @user2901683 Your new code does not really have anything to do with zipping anymore. Are you sure the file is not locked by your other code or even by another program? What's the source of those files?